# Precisely position a chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

When making a chart in the worksheet (not an independent chart sheet), is there a way to position the chart a little more precisely? Instead of just leaving it there "floating"?

I have a bunch of tables, one under another, and every table is going to have its own chart. Is there a way when I copy the first one, under the second one (just change the data) to make them exactly one under another ... not "wiggling" left/right?

I have Excel 2007.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on Windows (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Mac) when you move/resize charts to make them snap to the nearest row/column boundary.

Comment: Snaps to the centre of a row/column also, which is perfect for me needs.